# How to create linkedin company share with text and image, but without submitted-url

Tags: linkedin-api

Linkedin API allows to create company share with comment and content.
Content usually consists of submitted-image-url and submitted-url.

Share will appear as a text (comment) with image (submitted-image-url).
Share is clickable and click will redirect to submitted-url.

I would like to create a simple share with comment and image (submitted-image-url) with no reference to external article.

According to server responses, it is not possible to create a share without submitted-url.

```
{
    "errorCode": 0,
    "message": "'submitted-url' and 'media-key' can not be both empty",
    "requestId": ".......",
    "status": 400,
    "timestamp": 1470913993683
}
```

There is an undocumented attribute *media-key*. When this attribute is populated, server responds with:

```
{
    "errorCode": 0,
    "message": "Access to rich media share denied.",
    "requestId": ".......",
    "status": 403,
    "timestamp": 1470914142403
}
```

There is obviously undocumented part of API that allows image uploads.

My questions are:

1. Do you guys know any way to post an image share with text and without *submitted-url*?
2. Do you know where to ask for extended API permissions for our application?

Comment: I got this to work by passing `submitted-url` the same as `submitted-image-url` then instead of passing the `comment` I passed it as `title` so the post does not look funny. Probably not the answer you are looking for but it works for my use case, maybe it will work for yours.

Comment: Oh, passing the url for the image inline with the comment and leaving off other values also works.

Comment: I didn't know the second method (inlining url with comment) would work. But still, result is similar to using submitted-url the same as submitted-image-url. And sadly, that is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Sorry I could not help out more, I would like to see a proper solution too.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22340483/publishing-an-image-without-a-related-url-via-the-linkedin-api ?

Comment: Possible solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42130674/114558